# How to find missing value in python using sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I want to calculate mssing value by mean method from the dataset but it gives me

> error unhashable type: 'slice'

---

CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset= pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
m=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
X= pd.DataFrame(m)
n=dataset.iloc[:,-1].values
Y= pd.DataFrame(n)

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```

Comment: Kindly post the complete error.

Comment: Just try changing X[:,1:3] to X.iloc[:,1:3]

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** Slice a  DataFrame like below

```
 `'X[:,1:3]'`.
```

You should slice using `'iloc'` or another way round it would be using `'values'`

```
  'X.iloc[:,1:3]'

  'X.values[:,1:3]'
```